# VS Code Remote Debugging Python in a Docker container

Tags: python, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, remote-debugging, vscode-debugger

I am using VS Code's "Remove - WSL" extension to try to connect to a Docker container (backed by WSL2) running a Python job.

The python job is started somewhat like this:

```
exec python3 -m debugpy --listen 5678 --wait-for-client some_file.py
```

In my docker-compose.yml file I have set

```
ports:
  - "5678:5678"
```

And I run the service with

```
docker-compose up
```

My VS Code launch.json contains the following:

```
    {
        "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "connect": {
            "host": "localhost",
            "port": 5678
        },
        "pathMappings": [
            {
                "localRoot": "/home/myname/tensorflow_models/research",
                "remoteRoot": "/home/tensorflow/models/research"
            }
        ]
    }
```

However, running the above task briefly opens the debug bar and then closes it with no error message.

When I exec into the container I can run `netcat localhost 5678` and it will return json. However, it doesn't return anything when I run the same from WSL:

```
netcat localhost 5678
```

or on Windows from powershell:

```
powercat -c localhost -p 5678
```

Or even from within the container using the container's ip:

```
# Manually get ip address
ip a
# Doesn't return anything
netcat <ip> 5678
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that by default `debugpy` only listens on `localhost` (local connections only). The solution was to set the listen address to `0.0.0.0` (all addresses bound to the host):

```
exec python3 -m debugpy --listen 0.0.0.0:5678 --wait-for-client some_file.py
```